# How to backup files before overwriting them with rsync

Tags: bash, rsync

I'm using rsync to copy/deploy only the new/modified files from dev environment to test environment.
How can I backup the files (in test env) before overwriting them?
Just the ones that will be overwritten.

Cheers
Matteo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `--backup` option of `rsync`. It's useful to use `--backup-dir` or `--suffix` too.

> -b, --backup
>            With this option, preexisting destination files are renamed as
>                 each file is transferred or deleted.  You can control where the
>              backup file goes and what (if any) suffix gets appended using
>                 the --backup-dir and --suffix options

Comment: I've used rsync on cygwin and I've had a strange behaviour, in the backup folder I've found the new files, so I was thinking that the backup option is when you need the new files in a new location.
Now I've tried in ubuntu and the behaviour is what I need.
Thanks!